# How to solve simultaneous logical equations?

Tags: logic, systems-of-equations

Suppose I have two equations 
$$y = (x\oplus a)+b \\
  x = (y\oplus c)+d$$
All numbers are in base 10.

$\oplus$ is the XOR operation for binary numbers.

How do I solve such equations manually, or is there some Mathematica function I could use? I prefer not using matrices.

I did try using a C++ program to brute force it within a range, but it is not an ideal solution.

Comment: You should provide us with an order of operations or add some parantheses... Also: What is the $\operatorname{XOR}$ operator in base 10?

Comment: Basically it's the same XOR defined for binary numbers, but since I am using base-10, I need to convert it to binary, XOR, and then back to decimal. This is where a computer comes in handy.

Comment: So... Why wouldn't we work in base $2$? That seems a lot easier...

Comment: It is, but my inputs and outputs are provided as decimals, however converting it wouldn't be a problem. We *could* work in base 2. What I am interested is to get a method of solving the equations.

Comment: I might be mistaken but since the binary XOR is equivalent to addition modulo 2, wouldn't decimal XOR be the addition in base 10?

Comment: I'm not changing the definition of XOR. It's still the same as in binary.

Comment: @Cheese XOR is equivalent to addition modulo 2 only for each 'bit' - not for the number itself.